# How to make a xls file a datasource for JasperReports?

Tags: url, jasper-reports, datasource, xls

I have a web page that returns a xls file.

I'm trying to use the output of the page as a datasource for JasperReports.

Right now I have something like

```
JRXlsDataSource ds = new JRXlsDataSource(JRLoader.getLocationInputStream("http://192.168.20.19/people/XLS.jsf"));
```

but I get this error
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: jxl.read.biff.BiffException: The input file was not found

How can I read the stream and then use it in the JasperPrint object?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the report is working well when the source .xls file is local?

Comment: Everything is ok if I use a local file.

Comment: Hmmm... your code seems reasonable to me. I would investigate whether there's something funny with the input stream.

Comment: @JoaoHeleno Did you try to save 'remote' input stream as file and compare it with the local version (get it manually, for example) of file?

Comment: Right now I can't save files to disk (because of project rule) ... I have to read the InputStream to memory. My problem lies here... I know I have to do something else other than the getLocationInputStream...

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the link below, it would provide a complete idea of `XLS datasource` for jasper report

http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/xlsdatasource/index.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Answers which just contain links are [considered bad practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please summarize the content here (don't copy/paste) so the answer can stand on its own. If you don't you run the risk of your answer being removed, especially if the link ever dies.